# Permutation using backtracking with Python

Tags: python, list, append, permutation, backtracking

I am trying out the following backtracking solution for permutation of a list:

```
nums=[1, 2, 3]

def permute(nums):

    res = []
    track = []
    used = [0 for _ in range(len(nums))]

    def backtrack(nums, used, track):
        if len(track) == len(nums):
            res.append(track)
            return
        
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if used[i]:
                continue
            track.append(nums[i])
            used[i] = 1
            backtrack(nums, used, track)
            track.pop()
            used[i] = 0
    
    backtrack(nums, used, track)

    return res

res = permute(nums)
print(res)
```

It turns out after execution, you get:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Expected result is:

> ```
> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
> ```

Could you help point out which part of the code goes wrong and why?

Comment: Turned out if I change the line `res.append(track)` to `res.append(track[:])`, I will get the expected output, but why?

Comment: `track[:]` creates a new list. appending `track` only appends a reference to the old list which is then cleared by `track.pop()`.

Comment: Thanks @Banana, I did some experiments and it is indeed the case. I remembered I met with this problem before. Do it mean it is best to always append a list by `list[:]` other than `list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists passed to a function in python are references by default. I changed `backtrack(nums, used, track)` to `backtrack(nums, used, track.copy())` and it seemed to have solved the issue.

```
nums=[1, 2, 3]

def permute(nums):

    res = []
    track = []
    used = [0 for _ in range(len(nums))]

    def backtrack(nums, used, track):
        if len(track) == len(nums):
            res.append(track)
            return
        
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if used[i]:
                continue
            track.append(nums[i])
            used[i] = 1
            backtrack(nums, used, track.copy())
            track.pop()
            used[i] = 0
    
    backtrack(nums, used, track)

    return res

res = permute(nums)
print(res)
```

Comment: Every time it creates a new copy of track to pass into `backtrack` function and the reference of the new list is appended to `res`. Changing `res.append(track)` to `res.append(track.copy())` is more obvious (or the way @Banana suggested `res.append(track[:])`) in this case.  But this is very good solution and pointed out the cause of the issue and how to solve it.